# SSIS tab delimited export for mainframe consumption issue

Tags: ssis

Good afternoon, hope someone can shed some light on a strange issue that I am having.  I am running a simple SSIS flat file export job that creates a tab delimited flat file.  This file is to be consumed by our mainframe team but when they get the file they are seeing a period (.) character that precedes and ends each field.  I am wondering if the tab character that SSIS produces or uses is not being handled or is not what the mainframe expects it to be.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In addition to the points DaveE raises, you'll also need to look at how you transfer the file to the host for consumption. At my last job, we had issues with a windows copy (via a USS mount) whereas using ftp resulted in a non-mangled file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What encoding is your SSIS script outputting, and what encoding is the mainframe expecting?

The table [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlf101a.doc/xlflr/asciit.htm) indicates that the ASCII tab character (0x09) is a superscript indicator in EBCDIC.  IIRC (it's been a *looong* time), the period was used as a 'not printable' placeholder in mainframe output.

**EDIT**: And what character sets/code pages are in play?  ASCII <> EBCDIC, and CP437 (OEM) <> CP1252 (Windows Latin-1).

Comment: Yes I am trying to figure out what character encoding I will need to generate the file with.  It seems that the tab characters that SSIS is using is getting translated into a period or as my mainframe contact states 'an unreadable character'.  The odd thing is though that she says that the 'hex value is 05 and that it should appear as 40'.  Maybe that is a clue that someone with more mainframe experience can chime in on.

Comment: @mreyeros - How is the file getting to the mainframe? Is it being FTP'd or something?  It seems the basic translation is happening: 0x05 is EBCDIC 'Horizontal Tab', while 0x40 is a space. That translation my be an attribute of the transfer protocol if something like FTP is in use. The 0x40 thing is a bit of a puzzler - are they maybe expecting a fixed-format file with values space-delimited and -padded?  Does billinkc's comment on your original post fit your situation?

Comment: I have a feeling that it could be that what they really want is a fixed width file with padding as you state.  I am trying to confirm with them.  The specs show specific column/field lengths yet they are telling me that it is tab delimited.  Somewhere someone must have gotten something mixed up

Comment: Or they want *both* fixed width delimited files. Unfortunately, we had a number of flat files coming out of the mainframe that were fixed width (40 characters) that they then separated with a delimiter, pipe in my case. If there is numeric data and the Mainframers talk about BCD, binary coded decimal, packed data, comp-3, etc I wish you the very best but your simple extract is going to get ugly in a hurry.

Comment: <shivers> I'd forgotten about BCD & packing. Once upon a time I had to write SAS code to do that. 'ugly' might be a big understatement.

Comment: Ok it looks like my suspicions were correct, they do not need a tab delimited file but rather just fixed width.  I took one of my sample files and did a find and replace on all of the tabs and resubmitted via ftp and they informed me that it was perfect.  A few wasted hours later, now I just need to find the individual that asked for tab delimited :)  Thank you all for your help and input.